# Selecionar checkbox ao colocar valor de uma caixa de texto

Tags: javascript, html

Pretendo que ao colocar um valor no `<input type="number" />` selecione automaticamente o `<input type='checkbox' />`.

Segue meu HTML:

```
<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' 
      value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled /> 
   <strong style='color: #000000'>
      Peq. Almoço
   </strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' 
      type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' 
      value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim, chamando uma função com `oninput` enviando 2 parâmetros: `value` do `checkbox`, que servirá como seletor, e valor do `input`. Quando for `0`, desmarca o `checkbox`:

```js
function marcaBox(b,v){
   document.querySelector("[type='checkbox'][value='"+b+"']").checked = v > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled>
<strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong></div>  <div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
<input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value); marcaBox("Peq_Almoço", this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
```

### Para múltiplos elementos

A lógica é quase a mesma, mudando apenas os parâmetros e a forma de selecionar o `checkbox`:

```js
function marcaBox(e){
   var box = e.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']");
   box.checked = e.value > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled>
   <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value); marcaBox(this)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>

<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled>
   <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value); marcaBox(this)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>
```

Pode criar também eventos para cada `input`, aí neste caso não precisa chamar a função no `oninput`:

```js
var inputs_ = document.querySelectorAll("[type='number']");
for(var x=0; x<inputs_.length; x++){
   inputs_[x].addEventListener("input", function(){
      var box = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[type='checkbox']");
      box.checked = this.value > 0 ? true : false;
   });
}
```

```html
<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled>
   <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>

<div>
   <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled>
   <strong style='color: #000000'>Peq. Almoço</strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>
```

Comment: não funcionou, deve estar a faltar me alguma coisa. A função fica dentro deste script `<script type="text/javascript">function marcaBox(b,v){document.querySelector("[type='checkbox'][value='"+b+"']").checked = v > 0 ? true : false;}</script>`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, dentro do script.

Comment: Mas não está a seleccionar quando coloco valor no input

Comment: Tem só um ou são vários?

Comment: são vários inputs e vários checkbox

Comment: Adicionei na resposta outra forma com vários elementos.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77699/discussion-between-iniciante-and-dvd).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('checkboxAlmoco').onchange = function(){
document.getElementById('peqAlmoco').checked = true;
};
```

```html
<div>
   <input id="peqAlmoco" type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][OpcaoA]' 
      value='Peq_Almoço' $marcado_pequeno $disabled /> 
   <strong style='color: #000000'>
      Peq. Almoço
   </strong>
</div>
<div style='width:40%;position:relative;float:left'>
   <input id="checkboxAlmoco" $disabled min='0' oninput='this.value = Math.abs(this.value)' 
      type='number' name='arrachar[$year, $month, $day][Qtd]' 
      value='$marcado_pequeno_qtd' style='width:65px; height: 22px' />
</div>
```

Observe que adicionei id no seu código, sem ele não funciona